# How to make a bootable pendrive in command-line?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, usb-drive, iso, perl

How could a Bootable USB Pendrive can be created using the Ubuntu command-line. Can we use a script for the same?
Can somebody help on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `dd` utility.

First unmount your usb-drive and then get the device name with:

```
lsblk
```

Then create the bootable usb with:

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=/path/to/your.iso of=/dev/xxx && sync
```

Change `/dev/xxx` to your usb-drive device name.